# How to create new user in Quickblox using postman?

Tags: rest, api, quickblox

I want to create new user in quickblox using postman as shown in below image.
[image]

[image]

But the response is

```
{
   "errors": [
    "Token is required"
   ]
}
```

Could someone guide me where i had gone wrong

Comment: it may use some auth protocols. By the way your image links are broken

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hy1qhc. Please check this link

Comment: its probably use oauth2, google oauth2 or read this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: You have to provide token . You have to login to chat service to with SDK and get session token . That token  is required i each API call .Read [This](https://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization).